# Reshaping data in Pandas to have multi index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a raw data like the following

[image]

using Pandas I need to reshape like the following

[image]

Raw data's first row is header here. I need to take first row of data (which is second row here) to combine with header and create a multiindex like format.

Can't figure out how to reshape into the required format. Can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: you can read excel with 2 headers : `pd.read_excel(path_to_file.xlsx,header=[0,1],index_col=0).rename_axis([None,None],axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
s=df.T.set_index(['step1','step2']).T
```

Comment: getting close, one thing I forgot to add, that is there are indexes beside as this is a raw dataframe. so those indexes are becoming column names in that case. so step1, and step2 are not in the column names so that I can set index over them